# Get Date Range with Given Date

Tags: php, mysql, date, chart.js

I have the following query:

```
SELECT `date_created`, COUNT(`ID`) AS no_of_registration 
FROM (
  SELECT `id`, 
  DATE_SUB(DATE_ADD(MAKEDATE(from_unixtime(`created_on`,'%Y'), 7), 
  INTERVAL EXTRACT(WEEK FROM from_unixtime(`created_on`,'%Y-%m-%d')) WEEK), 
  INTERVAL WEEKDAY(DATE_ADD(MAKEDATE(from_unixtime(`created_on`,'%Y'), 1), 
  INTERVAL EXTRACT(WEEK FROM from_unixtime(`created_on`,'%Y-%m-%d')) WEEK)) -1 DAY)
  as `date_created` 
  FROM `users` WHERE 1) x 
GROUP BY `date_created` 
HAVING `date_created` BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 12 WEEK AND CURDATE()
```

This displays the data from the last 12 weeks using the date today. However, it only shows `date_created` as the Monday date. I'd like to show every week as a date range. Example: `2017-11-27 - 2017-12-04`.

Is this possible? I need it to display in my graph using chart.js.
[image]

Thanks for you help. -Eli

Answer (score 0):

Hello not sure that i have understood your problem but if you want only the monday, you can add in your where statement :

```
AND DAYOFWEEK(a.Date)=2
```